# Find 3rd highest cost from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

This is catalog table:

[image]

I have to find 3rd highest cost from this table .

I wrote this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 COST FROM CATALOG WHERE COST IN
 (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 COST FROM CATALOG ORDER BY COST DESC)
 ORDER BY COST ASC;
```

I got this error:

> from keyword not found where expected

Comment: database version?

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find `TOP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not recognize `TOP`.  You can do what you want but it requires additional subqueries (unless you are using Oracle 12c+):

```
SELECT MIN(COST)
FROM CATALOG
WHERE COST IN (SELECT COST
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COST
                     FROM CATALOG
                     ORDER BY COST DESC
                    ) c
               WHERE rownum <= 3
              );
```

Note:  As tempting as it might be, you cannot use `WHERE rownum = 3` in the subquery.  You can review the documentation for the explanation, but basically `rownum` does not get incremented until a row is placed in the result set.  So, `rownum = 1` *always* needs to be in the result set.

Finally, the normal way to do this in any (reasonable) database is to use `dense_rank()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, dense_rank() over (order by cost desc) as seqnum
      from category c
     ) c
where seqnum = 3;
```

Comment: i m using oracle 10 g

Comment: ONE MORE QUERY WHY R WE USING C HERE (SELECT COST
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COST
                     FROM CATALOG
                     ORDER BY COST DESC
                    )C

Comment: @SouvanikSaha . . . In order to use `rownum`.

Comment: Thanx alot @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12c+ then use `OFFSET`

```
SELECT COST 
FROM   CATALOG 
ORDER BY COST 
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I M USING ORACLE 10 G.

Comment: @SouvanikSaha - Then Gordan's answer should help you

Comment: @SouvanikSaha: STOP writing all uppercase. It's considered SCREAMING and rude